# How check password is exist or not for specified user?

Tags: active-directory

We can create user with password or without password(by disable the account).
How check password is exist or not for specified user?

Comment: We're going to need a LOT more info than that. What language ? How do you access your AD ? What is a "disabled" account ? How do you store passwords ? Can you provide us with your current tries ?

Comment: I tried using admistrator account.But how differentiate these two user accounts(user with password and user without password)?

Comment: If you repeat your question without providing the information that Growiel has asked for, you cannot expect an answer.

Comment: Default domain policy used.I did not change the policy.
disabled account:2 bit disabled in UAC.
when enable the disable account i got some error message like "Unable to update the password. The value provided for the new password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirement for the domain".I think password length is 0.